# Is dividing "randomly" the data set into 2 really effective?

Tags: time-series, cross-validation

Well, we all know that it's a great way to test the prediction capacity of the model. But lets say, for example, giving the data collected during 10 months, we are in the situation where the data during the first 7 months are more or less homogeneous, and less homogeneous during the last 3 months, i.e there are new patterns arrive only at the last 3 months.

1. If you divide your data set **randomly** into 2 set (the famous 70-30), you can end up conclude that the model works pretty well.
2. But if you divide your data set **with respect to time scale**, meaning that the first 7 months for training the model, and the last 3 months for the test. Well, the model will be less effective, and you may see that the model (may be) fails to predict the individual that it has never seen before.

Which is the better approach?

Comment: Just a general comment (maybe this is obvious already but I think it bears repeating): a fundamental assumption in using a test set to estimate the generalization error is that the distribution of future data matches the distribution of the data in the test set (generally it is assumed that the test set and future data are all iid draws from the same population). If that's not the case then the resulting test set estimate doesn't necessarily apply.

Answer (score 1):

Chaconne's comment is very useful.  If you believe the data you sample tomorrow will be from a (perhaps slightly) different distribution then the data you sampled today, then randomly drawn test set accuracy will under-estimate your error.  You more or less recommend the solution which is training on the past and testing on the future.

Separate from test set evaluation but relevant in the case of a slowly changing distribution is that *time decay* can be very useful to give more recent data more influence.  The amount of time decay should be established by cross validation, and the data division cross validation should always be training on old data and test on new data.

Comment: Then, if the data is homogeneous over the time, what is the benefits of deviding it randomly compared to the other approach?

Comment: Several things.  For one you can do it lots of times.  Cross validation is a bit more robust than a simple train/test split, and in cross validation you want every data point to appear in exactly one test set typically.  Perhaps I could rephrase, if the data is homogeneous over the time, what is the benefit of not dividing it randomly.

Comment: Yeah, agree that you can do it lots of times. So until now, we have one advantage of "randomly" over "dividing by time". But the disadvantage is that we risk of over-estimate the performance of the model built. Randomly dividing has advantages, and disadvantages. So why not use both in order to better estimate the model?